# Should the [brave] and [brave-browser] tags be merged, and if so, what should be the canonical tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

Both  [brave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/brave) and [brave-browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/brave-browser) tags refer to the brave browser.

Comment: Are both tags used correctly? I'm not familiar with any of them but doing a quick scan, [tag:brave] question have "Brave Wallet" in the title. Is Brave Wallet a feature of [tag:brave] (web-browser)?

Comment: @Rubén Yes, Brave Wallet is a feature of Brave Browser (it cannot be accessed except within Brave Browser)

Comment: This appears to have been completed already by Dharman, 21 hours ago.

Comment: @TylerH I added synonym, but the topic is still open in regards to what actually do with these tags.

Answer (score 26):

If the name of the browser did not use a common word like "brave", I'd be all for using the most obvious tag, [brave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/brave). However, "brave" is a very common word in English and I foresee other packages/libraries/frameworks/etc. using the name, if they haven't already.

Therefore, it is my suggestion to limit the tag to the browser only, using [brave-browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/brave-browser), leaving open the possibility of other tags for further creations by Brave Software (e.g., their [search engine](https://search.brave.com), their [Firewall/VPN service](https://brave.com/firewall-vpn/), etc., which may not have programming applicability now, but may in the future).

Comment: Agree with this. Deferring to the convention of like-tags is useful, but I agree that the possibility of another library/ tool called "brave" coming out some time down the line is _highly_ likely, and I think that reasoning is enough to trump matching convention in this case.

Comment: @zcoop98 I disagree.  Assuming another product called "brave" will pop up seems premature.  It's a problem you can worry about when it happens, if it ever does.

Comment: @MarkRansom Sure, but also we are using human-time right now to discuss and do something about it, I'd rather do it in a way that does not leave work for future folks by design. I don't see any downside to using brave-browser, whereas just brave is really not all that clear.

Answer (score 10):

Well Firefox has the tag [firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firefox), Safari has the tag [safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/safari) and Chrome has the tag [google-chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-chrome).

None of those tags contain the word browser so for consistency, neither should brave. After all if your issue is how do I use any of these browsers, it's off-topic here since you need to be asking a programming question.

Comment: Where these tags could be appropriately used are for browser specific bugs and features.  While much less common than the in the NS4 vs IE6 vs  FF1 era there are still things modern that work differently from one to the next.  ex Chrome, Firefox, and Safari have different ways of deciding if a video/audio file should be allowed to play at page load.

Comment: @DanIsFiddlingByFirelight sure but there's nothing really different between Brave and Chrome though.

Comment: Is the Brave browser really comparable with browsers such as Firefox, Safari and Chrome? Searching for usage share of browsers, it doesn't seem to be overly common. It's not uncommon to use short tags for generally known things but include the category for niche things; for example, various programming languages use a `-lang` postfix.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Brave is a Chromium based browser so it's the same code as Chrome apart from the UI and a few brave specific features e.g. they both use V8 for javascript. Chrome evolved from Safari/Webkit but Firefox has always been a completely independent codebase.

Comment: @RobertLongson I'm not questioning whether it is *technically* comparable but as a brand. Firefox, Safari and Chrome are something known as a browser even to just very mildly tech savy people; Brave as a browser is something I hadn't heard about before.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Brave, the web-browser, but AFAIK it isn't in the same league regarding number of users as the other web-browsers mentioned. Does "Brave" is like "Google" (a brand that names both a product and a company) or like "Firefox" / "Safari" (a brand that name a product, being completely different from the company name as Mozilla / Apple, respectively)?

Comment: I believe that tags should be optimized for clarity: brave as a browser is nothing (by orders of magnitude) close to the other three in terms of use. I think the very slight incoherence in tag names is insignificant in regard to have brave-browser meaning something.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with [the direction proposed in this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/420892/1079354), but in looking at the tag itself, I'm not sure...if the tag brings value.

Brave is a fork of Chrom(ium), so what runs in Chrom(ium) would run in Brave.  Any question on a strange CSS or JavaScript issue would essentially be equivalent across the two.

The questions I saw in the tags were about how to use the browser and general usage cases of it, which aren't on topic here.

Would it make more sense instead to tag the question based off of the base technology instead?  I wouldn't want this tag to be overloaded/conflated with this being a "Brave Browser support"-tag.

Comment: By that reasoning, we shouldn't have a tag for Microsoft Edge, or any number of other browsers that are Chromium-based but could very well differ from the base product. "Fork" != "Exactly the same as". Trust me, there are differences in the way Edge and Chrome render some things.